# Remove <br /> from textarea output

Tags: php, echo, line-breaks

I am using a plugin in Wordpress which outputs its text via the following -

```
<span class="value-text"><?php echo esc_html( $value_text ); ?></span>
```

However, if the original text entry contained line breaks the output looks like this -

```
line<br />
line
```

How can I output the text without `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

If you need only plain test the most easy solutions is to strip all tags

```
<span class="value-text"><?php echo strip_tags( esc_html( $value_text ) ); ?></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, this isn't working, the tag is still there. I get the feeling there is deeper code in the plugin that is causing it, I can find a few other references to $value_text. I'll probably contact the developer...

Comment: From what i read about the function ( it this is the proper doc ) [esc_html](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) it outputs formated html tags. So you can do 

`
<span class="value-text"><?php echo esc_html( strip_tags( $value_text ) ); ?></span>
`

First to pass the $value_text and then to esc_html.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "text<br />";
echo str_replace('<br />','',$string);
```

You can use like this:

```
<span class="value-text">
<?php echo str_replace('<br />','',esc_html($value_text)); ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress' built in `wp_strip_all_tags( string $string, bool $remove_breaks = false );` function, which has the `$remove_breaks` parameter if you want to completely remove `<br/>` styling from the output as well.

```
<span class="value-text"><?php echo esc_html( wp_strip_all_tags( $value_text, true ) ); ?></span>
```